# Why is my vector subscript out of range?

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-errors

Keep getting this error "Vector subscript out of range". I'm sure its because of this part of my code. Can anyone help me see what I'm doing wrong

```
bool set::remove(SET_ELEMENT_TYPE removalCandidate)
{
  int subscript = positionOf(removalCandidate);
  while( (subscript < my_size) && (my_element[subscript] != removalCandidate))
  {
     subscript++;
  }
  if(subscript = -1)
  {
    if(subscript == my_size)
      return false;
    else {
      while (subscript < my_size)
      {
        my_element[subscript] = my_element[subscript + 1];
        subscript++;
      }
      my_size--;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you calling it with and what is `my_size`?

Comment: In `if (subscript = 1)` it should be `==` not `=`. Also, why afterwards are you checking if `subscript` is equal to a whole other value when the if statement is only run when `subscript` is `-1`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 lol, not sure where I was going with it. Got carried away. So I dont need that code at all?

Comment: @0x499602D2 `set::set()
 { 
  my_size = 0; 
  my_index = 0; 
  my_capacity = DEFAULT_INITIAL_SET_CAPACITY;
  my_element.resize(my_capacity);`

Comment: Also, if `subscript` could possibly be `-1` (or any other invalid index of `my_element`), you should check that as the first thing you do in your method before you try to do the `[]` operator with it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You assign `-1` to `subscript` in this `if` condition:

```
if(subscript = -1)
```

The intention of this code is not clear.

You will access beyond your vector boundary in this loop at the point that the first access of `subscript` when it is `-1,`, and at the end of the loop when `subscript` is equal to `my_size - 1`.

```
while (subscript < my_size)
{
    my_element[subscript] = my_element[subscript + 1];
    subscript++;
}
```

This is because `my_element[-1]` is one behind the first element, and `my_element[my_size]` is reading one past the last element of your vector. You can change your test:

```
while (subscript + 1 < my_size)
{ //...
```

This fixes out of bounds at the end of the `while` loop, but you should fix the `if` condition to not assign to `subscript`.

Answer (score 0):

```
while( (subscript < my_size) && (my_element[subscript] != removalCandidate) )
```

Unless you are trying to have unique values in the Vector you don't need the && with the second part of your conditional. You are also not removing the 'removalCandidate' because you close the loop before getting to your IF statements.

@0x499602D2 is right in that you will be checking your Vector with a subscript that is -1. So you will always be out of range.

Lastly, the subscript at the end of your while loop will equal my_size and so when referencing

```
my_element[subscript]
```

that will also be out of range every time if your Vector's size is 10 but the referencing of the Vector begins at zero. So you should reference the Vector from 0 to (my_size-1).